# Switching between skins with DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I just need help with this, I'm building a web site and i want each user to choose the skin he wants, where i give him two options and he will choose the one he likes.

Is there any way to do this with DotNetNuke?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parameters that you can pass. **SkinSrc** and  **ContainerSrc** which take skin and container paths as values. Maybe you can keep the preference in a session then add to the querystring in page pre_init event.